# Compare 2 csv or excel files for string matches

Tags: python, shell

I want to compare sub-string between columns of 2 different files:

Below are the sample input and expected output

Input File1.csv:

```
1. Amar,18
2. Akbar,20
3. Anthony,21
```

Input File2.csv:

```
 1. Mr. Amar Khanna, Tennis 
 2. Mr. Anthony Rao, Cricket
 3. Federer, Badminton
```

Expected Output File3.csv:

```
 1. Amar,18,Tennis
 2. Anthony,21,Cricket
```

I am trying doing it using shell scripting. These are the solutions that I have tried so far to find the matches in two files:

1. diff file1 file2
   This did not work as it compares files for entire column match.
2. grep -f file1 file2 
   Even this did not work because of above issue.
3. awk 'FNR==NR{a[substr($1,5,8)];next} substr($1,5,8) in a' excel1.csv excel2.csv

This is not giving any result

Comment: Please show us your code and a sample output of both CSV and the code you tried so fare.

Comment: I have changed it to shell now. I tried doing it using grep commands: grep -f excel1.csv excel2.csvt using

Comment: Edit your question and add what you tried and what happened to make the question as clear as possible. Keep in mind SO's purpose is to give answers to other programmers facing the same issue/challenge. So it needs to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to compare? Whether file records number or particular record of one file to another record of another file?